# bigquery load from json fails

Tags: json, python-3.x, google-bigquery

I am trying to load a json file from google cloud storage to bigquery and am hitting an error that I am not fully understanding. I want to load the json without getting autodetected. Basically, the complete json from test.json should show up as a row in the table.

**Here's my python script:**

```
 from google.cloud import bigquery
 from google.api_core.exceptions import BadRequest
 
 project_id="myprojectid"
 client = bigquery.Client(project=project_id)
 
 dataset_id = "mydataset"
 table_id="mytable"
 
 table_fqdn = "{}.{}.{}".format(project_id, dataset_id, table_id)
 
 job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig(
     #schema=[
     #    bigquery.SchemaField("json_data", "JSON")
     #],
     autodetect=False,
     source_format=bigquery.SourceFormat.NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON
 )
 
 uri = "gs://mybucket/test.json"
 
 load_job = client.load_table_from_uri(
     uri,
     table_fqdn,
     location="US",
     job_config=job_config
 )  
 
 job_resource = load_job.to_api_repr() 
 
 print(job_resource)
 
 try:
     load_job.result()
 except BadRequest as e:
     print(load_job.errors)
     raise e
```

I have the following bigquery table with one column having json data type:

```
   Last modified          Schema         Total Rows   Total Bytes   Expiration   Time Partitioning   Clustered Fields   Total Logical Bytes   Total Physical Bytes   Labels  
  ----------------- -------------------- ------------ ------------- ------------ ------------------- ------------------ --------------------- ---------------------- -------- 
   1 Jan 00:00:00   |- json_data: json   0            0                                                                 0
```

**This is the file I am trying to load:**

**test.json**

> {
> "a": 1,
> "b": 2,
> "c": 3,
> "d": 4
> }

I want the json to load as is and not get parsed, hence why I have `autodetect=False`

I don't understand why I am getting the following error:

```
 {'jobReference': {'projectId': 'myproject', 'jobId': '5cg1c3d3-xxxx-4c19-xxxx-90a902ec25b2', 'location': 'US'}, 'configuration': {'load': {'sourceUris': ['gs://mybucket/test.json'], 'schema': {'fields': [{'name': 'json_data', 'type': 'JSON'}]}, 'destinationTable': {'projectId': 'myproject', 'datasetId': 'jason_test', 'tableId': 'json_tbl'}, 'sourceFormat': 'NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON', 'autodetect': False}, 'jobType': 'LOAD'}}
 [{'reason': 'invalid', 'location': 'gs://mybucket/test.json', 'message': 'Error while reading data, error message: JSON table encountered too many errors, giving up. Rows: 1; errors: 1. Please look into the errors[] collection for more details. File: gs://mybucket/test.json'}, {'reason': 'invalid', 'message': 'Error while reading data, error message: JSON processing encountered too many errors, giving up. Rows: 1; errors: 1; max bad: 0; error percent: 0'}, {'reason': 'invalid', 'location': 'gs://mybucket/test.json', 'message': 'Error while reading data, error message: JSON parsing error in row starting at position 0: Expected key File: gs://mybucket/test.json'}]
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "bq-load.py", line 84, in <module>
     raise e
   File "bq-load_json.py", line 79, in <module>
     load_job.result()
   File ".local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/google/cloud/bigquery/job/base.py", line 728, in result
     return super(_AsyncJob, self).result(timeout=timeout, **kwargs)
   File ".local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/google/api_core/future/polling.py", line 137, in result
     raise self._exception
 google.api_core.exceptions.BadRequest: 400 Error while reading data, error message: JSON table encountered too many errors, giving up. Rows: 1; errors: 1. Please look into the errors[] collection for more details. File: gs://mybucket/test.json
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you confirm whether your  table has only one column or not?What do you mean by `a,b,c,d` in test.json { "a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3, "d": 4 }.

Comment: It only has 1 column

Answer (score 1):

To work correctly, if you set `autodetect` to `False`, you have to set a schema in the `JobConfig` object.

Also an important things, the fields in the `Json` file needs to match exactly the schema of the `BigQuery` table, example :

```py
 from google.cloud import bigquery
 from google.api_core.exceptions import BadRequest
 
 project_id="myprojectid"
 client = bigquery.Client(project=project_id)
 
 dataset_id = "mydataset"
 table_id="mytable"
 
 table_fqdn = "{}.{}.{}".format(project_id, dataset_id, table_id)
 
 job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig(
     schema=[
         bigquery.SchemaField("a", "INT64"),
         bigquery.SchemaField("b", "INT64"),
         bigquery.SchemaField("c", "INT64"),
         bigquery.SchemaField("d", "INT64")
     ],
     autodetect=False,
     source_format=bigquery.SourceFormat.NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON
 )
 
 uri = "gs://mybucket/test.json"
 
 load_job = client.load_table_from_uri(
     uri,
     table_fqdn,
     location="US",
     job_config=job_config
 )  
 
 job_resource = load_job.to_api_repr() 
 
 print(job_resource)
 
 try:
     load_job.result()
 except BadRequest as e:
     print(load_job.errors)
     raise e
```

In this example, I created a schema in `JobConfig` object based on your `Json` line :

```json
{ "a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3, "d": 4 }
```

**Other solution without schema and without autodetect :**

```py
from typing import List, Dict

import ndjson
from google.cloud import storage, bigquery


def load_json_file_to_bigquery():
    storage_client = storage.Client()

    bucket_name = "bucket-name"
    filename = "sample_json_output.json"

    bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(bucket_name)

    blob = bucket.get_blob(filename)

    json_data_string = blob.download_as_string()

    # Convert the json lines String to a List of Dict with the ndjson lib.
    json_data_as_dicts: List[Dict] = ndjson.loads(json_data_string)

    # Insert List of Dict to BigQuery.
    bq_client = bigquery.Client()
    results = bq_client.insert_rows_json('dataset.table', json_data_as_dicts)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    load_json_file_to_bigquery()
```

For this solutions, the steps are :

- Load the `NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON` file with the `storage` client as `STRING`
- In this case it's not an usual json format, I used the library [ndjson](https://pypi.org/project/ndjson/) to convert the `Json` lines `String` to a List of Dict
- Use the `insert_rows_json` proposed by `BigQuery` client, to save the List of Dict to `BigQuery`. The binding is done between the `BigQuery` table and the types provided by the `Dict`. No need to give a schema with this method.
- If you have the possibility to use an usual `Json` format (not Json Line), no need to use a library. You can directly convert the result String to a List of Dict with `json.loads`.

Comment: Is there a way to load the valid json entirely without specifying the schema? For example, there will be differences in the keys over time (one might have keys a to z while another just have a to d)

Comment: If you set your fields as NULLABLE in `BigQuery`, you can add the schema and if some field are missing, it will still work. I think in this case, you can also use the autodetect mode but it’s better having a schema. If you can’t use these 2 solutions, I can propose you another approach without schema and without autodetect.

Comment: I edited my answer to give you the other solution without a schema and autodetect. I hope it helps.